# PyInstaller, make module unimportable like in normal Python

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a problem while making `FSCMD` (Not that Oracle but this 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rvqTvx92vM') test debug to compile,

My problem is that when I compile the script, the `lexer.py` module is compiled too, so you can remove the `lexer.py` module from the `include` module. But that's not what I want, I want the `lexer.py` to be editable so `FSCMD` is full open-source

For more clearer, this is what my problem like (example code) (sort of)

```
import test_file # importing the test_file

test_file.test_function(test_parameter) # this is just a little code
```

If the `test_file` module does not exist, this will raise an exception, but when I compile this piece of code with `pyinstaller`, and the `test_file` module does not exist, this will run normally and no exception

What I want is that if I remove the `test_file` module, the compiled python code will raise an exception because we can edit the `test_file` and `test_file` module is not editable if `pyinstaller` compile the code and the imported module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind guys, I know how to do it. FSCMD won't import include folder because sys.path didn't have any `include` directory, so I use `extend` to add, and to make FSCMD raise an exception

First, add `sys.path` before the imported module

```
import sys, os, ...

try
 sys.path.extend([os.path.abspath(""), os.path.abspath("include")])
except:
 pass
```

This piece of code tells if I use the `--exclude` is exist, then import that module. If I don't use this piece of code, then there will be an error

Second, compile and exclude the `include` folder

```
pyinstaller .... --exclude include
```

Now if `include` does not exist, this will raise an exception

Here is my programming language link https://github.com/Faran2007/FSCMD Or
https://www.mediafire.com/file/iyyusbifz8qf83p/FSCMD_Version_0.1_Muhammad_Faran_Aiki.zip/file and 
https://mega.nz/#!j7BUjYgB and you can find more about this programming language